# Can't receive the messag in Akka Cluster

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, distributedpubsub

I'm attempting to send a message from senderActor within Microservice A using the concept of "Classic Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster" I'm trying to publish the message to the content-topic, but I'm not receiving it in the ReceiverActor located in Microservice B. Do you have any insight into what might be causing this issue?

Thank you!

the Conf-file in A

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      canonical {
        hostname = "localhost"
        port = 2551
      }
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka://cluster-system@localhost:2551"
    ]
  }
}
```

The SenderActor:

```
public class SenderActor extends AbstractActor {
    ActorRef mediator = DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();
    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(
                        String.class,
                        in -> {
                            String out = in.toUpperCase();
                            mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish("content", out), getSelf());
                        })
                .build();
    }
}
```

the main in Microservice A:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceAaApplication.class, args);
        Config config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf");

        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("cluster-system", config);
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.get(system);
        ActorRef publisher = system.actorOf(Props.create(SenderActor.class), "publisher");
        publisher.tell("hello from microservice A ", null);
        
    }
```

the Conf-file in B

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      canonical {
        hostname = "localhost"
        port = 2552
      }
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka://cluster-system@localhost:2551"
    ]
  }
}
```

The ReceiverActor class:

```
public class ReceiverActor extends AbstractActor {
    LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);
    public ReceiverActor() {
        ActorRef mediator = DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();
        mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe("content", getSelf()), getSelf());
    }
    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(String.class, msg -> {
                    log.info("Received message in receiver-actor-b: {}", msg);
                })
                .match(DistributedPubSubMediator.SubscribeAck.class,
                        msg -> log.info("SubscribeAck: {}", msg))
                .build();
    }
}
```

the main in Microservice B:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceBbApplication.class, args);
        Config config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf");

        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("cluster-system", config);
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.get(system);
        ActorRef subscriber = system.actorOf(Props.create(ReceiverActor.class), "subscriber");
    }
```

itry to get the message "hello from microservice A ", but i get just the flowings logs in B:

```
2023-08-20T15:53:14.067+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [           main] c.e.M.MicroserviceBbApplication          : Started MicroserviceBbApplication in 0.909 seconds (process running for 1.723)
2023-08-20T15:53:14.552+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger             : Slf4jLogger started
2023-08-20T15:53:14.900+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] akka.remote.artery.ArteryTransport       : Remoting started with transport [Artery tcp]; listening on address [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552] with UID [6730186213375081245]
2023-08-20T15:53:14.925+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] akka.cluster.Cluster                     : Cluster Node [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552] - Starting up, Akka version [2.8.3] ...
2023-08-20T15:53:14.980+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] akka.cluster.Cluster                     : Cluster Node [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
2023-08-20T15:53:14.981+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] akka.cluster.Cluster                     : Cluster Node [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552] - Started up successfully
2023-08-20T15:53:15.006+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [t-dispatcher-13] akka.cluster.Cluster                     : Cluster Node [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552] - No downing-provider-class configured, manual cluster downing required, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster.html#downing
2023-08-20T15:53:15.624+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [t-dispatcher-13] akka.cluster.Cluster                     : Cluster Node [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552] - Received InitJoinAck message from [Actor[akka://cluster-system@localhost:2551/system/cluster/core/daemon#1745370250]] to [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552]
2023-08-20T15:53:15.675+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [t-dispatcher-13] akka.cluster.Cluster                     : Cluster Node [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2552] - Welcome from [akka://cluster-system@localhost:2551]
2023-08-20T15:53:16.077+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [lt-dispatcher-5] c.example.MicroserviceBB.ReceiverActor   : SubscribeAck: SubscribeAck(Subscribe(content,None,Actor[akka://cluster-system/user/subscriber1#-339648796]))
2023-08-20T16:24:19.549+02:00  INFO 7788 --- [t-dispatcher-40] akka.actor.CoordinatedShutdown           : Running CoordinatedShutdown with reason [JvmExitReason]

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to remember that Distributed PubSub will only deliver messages to subscribers that happen to be subscribed at the time the mediator receives the published message (I'm simplifying a bit, but that's the intuition to have).

In Microservice A's `main`, you start the cluster forming (the process of forming the cluster happens in the background) and then immediately spawn the `SenderActor` and send it a message, which gets forwarded to the mediator.  Note also that the cluster can form with just one node (since Microservice A defines itself as a seed node), so you're sending the message to the mediator before the `ReceiverActor` in Microservice B has subscribed; as a consequence, the message is dropped.

In this case, it may be useful to have an actor in Microservice A which is subscribed to a different pubsub topic; the `ReceiverActor` publishes to that topic that it has subscribed to the `"content"` topic, which causes the subscribing actor in Microservice A to `tell` the `SenderActor` that it can publish messages to the topic.

As a side note, it's not clear if Microservices A and B are meant to be instances of the same microservice or are truly different microservices.  If the latter, [it's not recommended to use Akka Cluster for communication between microservices](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/choosing-cluster.html#microservices).

Comment: Hi Levi, 

Thanks a lot for your help – everything’s working now. 
can you answer the question below ?